# Pivot Table (Crosstab Report) in Java EE Web Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, crosstab

What is the best option of rendering crosstab report/pivot table in Java EE Web Application - using any of the JSP/Servlet framework such as Struts/Spring/JSF?

We have been using reporting frameworks like Jasper Reports or BIRT to achieve this. Even ADF Faces from Oracle have the capability.

We would like to evaluate some thing lighter - displayTag kind of light weight library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this posting is quite old and still lacks any answer.  There might be open source options for both reporting styles, but I have never been able to find them. So I thought I would offer my company's solution which is custom J2EE templates offered as parts of our tool suite, m-Power.  The following links are working online examples:

Web Pivot Table Report:
http://www.crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.R00180s

Web Cross-Tab Report:
http://mrc-productivity.com/mrcjava/servlet/MRCFORUM.R01273s

These are just two examples of many reports/apps you can make with m-Power.

Answer (score 0):

Look for JPalo. I also recall one in ZK framework an a JS one in TreeGrid. You can also easily render BIRT report in a webpage, but this one won't be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is a great choice. It is pure javascript component so that you can easily embed it into any web application.

Here is [Demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [Documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).